# Grails - Rendered Json file too huge for client side operations

Tags: json, grails, csv, grails-orm

I have a grails controller to render json files as follows, to be further used by d3 on my front end (.gsp file):

```
def dataSource
def salesjson = {
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def rows = sql.rows("select date_hour,mv,device,department,browser,platform,total_revenue as metric, total_revenue_ly as metric_ly from composite")
    sql.close()        
    render rows as JSON
}
```

I use this file to render my crossfiltered dc-charts on the front end. The problem is, queries such as the one above returns large JSON file / object and my client stops working and hangs. (100MB plus, on the client side, and still loading!!)

I can't think of any alternative to this method, which would reduce my file size (maybe rendering as a csv string? Would that help a lot? If so, how do I go about it? I have about 600,000 rows in my json currently)

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using something like [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) to create more binary like smaller representations of your JSON.  There are a few other options out there, but I think this one is probably the most JVM / Javascript friendly.

Comment: Interesting. Will look into it. Meanwhile, my json file is so huge Chrome devtools gives me a 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error when I try to run my application (DC-charts created on the front end.) Is this error only due to the size of the file? Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Also, would me rendering my JSON from my controller be a reason for the long load time? Msgpack is something to do with services. I know, ideally, my rendering should be in a JSON, but does it make that much of a difference? Thanks for responding. Quite the amateur here!